# Using VBA to request specific attribute on online XML

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Recently I was trying to write a custom function in VBA for excel that would fetch stock information from a Webservice. However, the resulting XML is written like this:

```
<ComportamentoPapeis>
<Papel Codigo="BOVA11" Nome="ISHARES BOVA CI" 
       Ibovespa="" Data="29/05/2015 17:29:57" 
       Abertura="52,04" Minimo="51,28" Maximo="52,24" 
       Medio="51,64" Ultimo="51,35" Oscilacao="-1,98"/>
</ComportamentoPapeis>
```

I tried to write the following piece of code, but as I run it, it says that the Method or Data was not found.

```
    Function STOCK(sName As String, sItem As String, Optional sURL = "") As Variant
    Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmlResp As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim result As Variant
    On Error GoTo EH


    If sURL = "" Then
        sURL = "http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-" & _
                "Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel="
    End If

    'open the request and send it
    oHttp.Open "GET", sURL & sName, False
    oHttp.Send

    'get the response as xml
    Set xmlResp = oHttp.responseXML

    ' get Item
    STOCK = xmlResp.SelectSingleNode("/ComportamentoPapeis/Papel"). _
                 Atrributes.getNamedItem(sItem).Text


    ' Examine output of these in the Immediate window
    Debug.Print sName
    Debug.Print xmlResp.XML

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xmlResp = Nothing
    Set oHttp = Nothing
Exit Function
EH:
    STOCK = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    GoTo CleanUp
End Function
```

In this particular case, sName = BOVA11 and sItem = Nome

Does somebody know what went wrong? I already referenced it to MSXML v6.0

Answer (score 0):

`Atrributes.getNamedItem(sItem).Text` - there is a typo in `Attributes`

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent hours trying to find the mistake and was defeated by a single typo!